# updating postgres table using gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm having trouble trying to update rows in my table.
I have tried the following:

```
return ss.db.Where("name = ?", sub.Name).Save(&sub).Error
```

and

```
return ss.db.Save(sub).Error
```

I've also tried variations of this

```
s := ss.db.Where("Name = ?", sub.Name)
    return ss.db.Model(&s).Updates(Subscription{Name: sub.Name, DevicesAllowed: sub.DevicesAllowed, Price: sub.Price, Active: sub.Active}).Error
```

I have also tried several other approaches that havent worked, for example, this attempt results in all the rows being changed:

```
return ss.db.Model(&sub).Updates(Subscription{Name: sub.Name, DevicesAllowed: sub.DevicesAllowed, Price: sub.Price, Active: sub.Active}).Error
```

I have the rest of the code here in a gist for reference: https://gist.github.com/yshuman1/8a26a90507bc13de7290d3adc0facdd1

Any help or advice would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: *"this attempt results in the rows being changed"* what do you mean by this? Did the update work or did it not? If the rows got changed then you've solved your problem, no?

Comment: @mkopriva sorry missed a word there...what i meant is "this attempt results in all the rows being changed"

I'll edit the post to reflect that.

Comment: I see that you tried `ss.db.Save(sub)`, did you also try `ss.db.Save(&sub)` ? And does the `sub` value have its `ID` properly set? Also calling `db.Where` without first specifying the table or model doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @mkopriva using ss.db.Save(&sub) created a new row. I modified my db.Where to specify the model. here my latest attempt:
https://gist.github.com/yshuman1/18809f77828d55d15db6da1b0649dc6e
it looks up the row properly but doesnt update anything.

Comment: I just realized in that gist i was saving the old info as well so i corrected it to &sub instead of subscription. so i edited the code a bit and now it works. its not pretty but it works lol. heres a snippet: https://gist.github.com/yshuman1/50045310ef49d69ea7f072f58d760650 Thank you so much @mkopriva, i wouldnt have figured it out without your help.

Answer (score 1):

the solution was to find the record int he table and then replace the old values with the new ones prior to using .Save() like this:

```
func (ss *SubscriptionService) Update(sub *Subscription) error {
    var subscription Subscription
    db := ss.db.Where(&Subscription{Name: sub.Name})
    err := first(db, &subscription)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("error looking up subscription")
        return err
    }
    subscription.Price = sub.Price
    subscription.Active = sub.Active
    subscription.DevicesAllowed = sub.DevicesAllowed
    return ss.db.Save(&subscription).Error
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `sub` in `first` and `Save`? ie. `err := first(db, sub)`, then error check and then `return db.Save(sub).Error` without doing the reassignments?

Comment: Actually something like [this](https://play.golang.com/p/N6ed2868Yre) should be enough as long the `sub`'s ID is set.

Comment: i tried the latter of your suggestions and it created another row, and ignored my changing active to false.  curl -d 'Name=test22&DevicesAllowed=100&Price=15&Active=false' -v http://localhost:3000/submgr/update 
here's a screencap of the table 
https://imgur.com/jlsy3eM